# How to run sync queries in knex [Node]

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, knex.js

How to results in sync manner in knex db in node.
http://knexjs.org/#Promises-then

```
knex.select('*').from('users').where({name: 'Tim'})
  .then(function(id) {
    console.log('Inserted Account ' + id);
  })
```

i want something like this

```
knex.select('*').from('users').where({name: 'Tim'})
  .sync().then(function(id) {
    console.log('Inserted Account ' + id);
  }); // code should not continue to run until completing then function
```

**or**

how to make async lib to run multiple parallel tasks and return results in sync code. like below or something like that

```
               var results=async.sync().parallel([
                    task1,task2
                ],function(err, res){
                    results=res;
                }); // anything like var results or sync()
                console.log(results);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would question your need to run things in "sync mode". There is likely some flow control you can establish, and at worst you could be severely impacting your NodeJS server. Due to NodeJS's single-threaded architecture, what you are suggesting is to have all other events/users wait until the current action calls the DB and returns. This is not a good use of NodeJS.

From what I can tell from your question, something like `async.parallel` should work for you.

```
async.parallel({
  queryone: function( parCb ){
    var query = knex('users').select().where( 'name', 'Tim' );
    query.exec( function(err, results ) {
      parCb( err, results );
    } );
  },
  querytwo: function( parCb ){
    var query = knex('otherTable').select().where( 'name', 'Tim' );
    query.exec( function(err, results ) {
      parCb( err, results );
    } );
  },
},
function(err, results) {
  //Results are all ready, containing the results of two different queries
  console.log( 'Results for queryone: ' + JSON.stringify( results.queryone ) );
  console.log( 'Results for querytwo: ' + JSON.stringify( results.querytwo ) );
});
```

Here, when you reach the `function(err,results)` callback, `results` is filled with the data from the two queries, executing in parallel. All without completely blocking your other events.

Comment: if there is another line after calling async.parallel then will it execucated before results are made or not?

Comment: `async.parallel` is done asynchronously. So the call is made, it's events are put into the event queue, and the code moves on. As those events are resolved (and in this case, when all the events have resolved in parallel), the callback `function(err,results)` is made, filled with the results! This is the nature of the NodeJS platform. Be sure to take some time understanding what is being done there . . . running everything in a synchronous manner is not the correct approach.

Comment: i know about that, that why i want async.parallel to return results syncly but run given tasks parallel. i don't want to run code after async.parallel until async.parallel has done all tasks and made results

Comment: Correct. The final callback for `async.parallel` is only called when all the tasks have finished. So you're code is "sync'd up" at that point and you can know that all calls have completed. Check out [the documentation](https://github.com/caolan/async#parallel) as well. Mark as answer if this all has helped you.

Comment: i want console.log(results); just after (not inside) calling async.parallel

Comment: If you put `console.log(results)` after the `async.parallel` call, and not inside the callback, it will execute before *any* tasks in the parallel list are run. The correct place to call `console.log(results)` is inside that callback, and using a Promise, or some async pattern, is the correct way to program what you are doing inside NodeJS. NodeJS _is_ asynchronous and trying to make things synchronous will cause problems for you unless you understand _why_ you need it that way. Control flow is an important topic in NodeJs land, especially for multiple DB calls.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
async getOne(table, { fields = '*', filters = {} }) {
     const promise = new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {                
        knex(table).where(filters).select(fields).first().then((result) => {
            resolve(result);
        }).catch((err) => resolve({}));
     });

     return await promise;
}
```

Then

```
let data = (await getOne('demo', {})).map(d => return d);
```

Now data variable is a array.